# Pass multiple parameter to Powershell inline script in Advanced Installer

Tags: powershell, installation, custom-action, advanced-installer

I'm using advanced installer for creating msi package I want copy some files and folders  after installation completed to "[APPDIR]" (I know I can do this with add files and folder to files and folder section in advanced installer but I don't want to do that because my files and folder are dynamic in each installation in customer machine)
I write an inline PowerShell script like below

```
> Param( [string] $source, [string] $dest )
$exclude = @('web.config')
> Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | Copy-Item
> -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.FullName.Substring($source.length)}
```

and in the parameter section, I fill like this `"[SourceDir]Project", "[APPDIR]Project"`

but it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abbas has since confirmed that the **problem was one of *command-line (parameter) syntax***:

The parameter section - what to pass to the PowerShell script from [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) - was filled in as:

```
"[SourceDir]Project", "[APPDIR]Project"  # !! WRONG, due to the comma
```

whereas it should have been:

```
"[SourceDir]Project" "[APPDIR]Project"  # OK: *space-separated* arguments
```

**Calling scripts/functions/cmdlets in PowerShell works as it does in *shells***, not as in programming languages; that is, **you must separate the arguments being passed with *spaces*.**

By contrast, using `,` between tokens constructs an *array* that is passed as a *single* argument.

From PowerShell run [`Get-Help about_Command_Syntax`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_syntax) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, you need to give more details. What are the execution settings for your PS custom action?

Have you checked the [verbose log](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/read-log.html) to see the params are passed correctly?

Your custom action should be scheduled as deferred with no impersonation, so it is executed after the APPDIR folder is created by the setup package and it has all the rights to write in that location.

Also, you should add rollback and uninstall custom actions to cleanup the files, as during an uninstalled or a canceled/failed installation, those resources will not be cleaned up by Windows Installer.